# Can C# interfaces behave in the same way as Rust traits?

Tags: c#, syntax

I have the following C# models (theoretical example):

```cs
public class Filename
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

namespace Protobuf // Auto-generated
{
    public class Filename
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to convert the 'Filename' type to the 'Protobuf.Filename' type using a simple method.

Now I know Rust as well. In this situation I would create a trait in Rust and implement it on the 'Filename' type like so:

```rust
trait ToProto<TProto> {
    fn to_proto(&self) -> TProto;
}

impl ToProto<protobuf::Filename> for Filename {
    fn to_proto(&self) -> protobuf::Filename {
        protobuf::Filename {
            format_string: self.format_string,
            description: self.description,
        }
    }
}
```

Something similar is possible in Swift with protocols and extensions, as far as I'm aware.

I was thinking of using interfaces and extension methods in C#, but these didn't seem to cooperate very well with each other.
This, for example, isn't valid C#:

```cs
public interface IProtoConvertible<T, TProto>
{
    public TProto ToProto(this T value);
}
```

I can just ommit the interface alltogether and just use extension methods, but that results in a lot of repeated code that screams "This can be more generic!".

Am I overlooking something? Is this possible in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be looking for abstract classes? Interfaces cannot contain any implementation and are implemented, not inherited. An abstract class on the other hand, can contain concrete conversion methods.

Comment: I think the short answer in this specific case is: "no"; however, if you have a pre-existing code version of `Filename`, have you considered using protobuf-net instead of Google.Protobuf, which makes it easy to use your existing model with protobuf? i.e. `[ProtoContract] public class Filename { [ProtoMember(1)]  public string Name { get; set; } [ProtoMember(2)] public string Description { get; set; } }` (I know this isn't what you *asked* - I'm trying to look beyond the question into what you're trying to *achieve*, rather than how you're currently trying to do it)

Comment: I'm not sure how the rust code is better? I don't know rust, but you still have to write an implementation for each pair of such types, don't you?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/extensions.md, and discussed at https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/2023/LDM-2023-02-22.md#extensions?

Comment: @MarcGravell That definitly looks interesting, and it's also pretty close to what I am trying to achieve :). Does it generate protobuf files that can be used with existing protobuf? Or does my whole schema need to be defined in C# in that case?

Comment: @katkak you can work code-first or contract-first; the library can generate a .proto schema from your code via `Serializer.GetProto<T>()` - although obviously it is often lacking a little nuance vs hand-written schemas

Comment: @Sweeper The Rust code is better in the sense that it allows me to do this. The interface example in C# does not compile. Interfaces cannot define extension methods and static classes (needed to define extension methods) cannot implement interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved my issue using [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/).

It allows me to define a Profile like this:

```cs
using AutoMapper;

public class FilenameProfile : Profile
{
    public FilenameProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Filename, Protobuf.Filename>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Later on I can then use IMapper (injected with DI) to convert from one Filename to the other:

```cs
var protoFilename = new Protobuf.Filename()
{
    ...
};

var filename = _mapper.Map<Filename>(protoFilename);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
public interface IProtoConvertible<T, TProto> where T : class
                                              where TProto : class
{
    public TProto ToProto<T>(T value)
    {
        // implementation here
        // return (TProto)new object();
    }
}
```

Since C# 8.0 it is possible to write implementation in interface methods.